# Meteor filtering data when asserting fields from queries

Tags: meteor

Why does running this code

```
var userId = Meteor.userId();
var user   = Users.findOne(userId, { fields: { earnings: 1 } });
```

Return

```
 { _id: 'Co5bMySeaqySgDP6h', earnings: { period: 0.6, total: 52.5 } }
```

Instead of returning all the fields on the user, including the earnings (custom field)

Also, is there a way to make user queries automatically return custom specified fields, so I dont have to manually specify it each time I need it?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you only get the specified field (plus the id) is given in [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#fieldspecifiers):

> To include *only* specific fields in the result documents, use 1 as the value. The _id field is still included in the result.

If instead you just call `Meteor.users.findOne(userId)` it will return all of the *available* fields.  If this is called on the server, that will be the entire document, but if you use it on the client, it will only return the fields that have been published from the server, which by default is just the username and the `emails` and `profile` fields.  Again, per [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user):

> On the client, this will be the subset of the fields in the document that are published from the server (other fields won't be available on the client). By default the server publishes username, emails, and profile (writable by user). See Meteor.users for more on the fields used in user documents.

This means that if you have added a new field to you user docs, you need to explicitly publish it for it to be available on the client (assuming autopublish has been removed).  Note that it's fine to do this using the previously discussed fields specifier as the other required details (username, profile) will not be overwritten by another publish function unless you try to publish the same top-level field again.

```
Meteor.publish('earnings', function() {
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, { fields: { earnings: 1 } });
};
```

(Publish functions expect you to return a cursor rather than an array, so you need to use `find` rather than `findOne` even if there will only be one result).

Finally, it's easy to add your own methods to a collection to make finding stuff you want more concise.

```
Meteor.users.findSimple = function(selector, options) {
  options = options || {};
  options.fields = options.fields || {};
  options.fields.earnings = 1;
  \\ same thing for any other fields you want to limit this find to;
  return this.find(selector, options);
};
```

Comment: Great clarification, much appreciated